# finding a shared folder in an IP address in VBA

Tags: windows, vba

I am trying to find a string in the list of shared folder names in an IP address in VBA.
The below routine works for folders but does not work. The error it says is Err-76, path not found.
could any one tell me how to access shared folder names in an IP address.

```
Sub findfolder()
Dim myFolder As Folder
Dim objfile As Object
Dim subfolder As Object
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim txt As String
Dim strname As String

txt = "\\10.4.32.33"
'spath = GetFolder(txt)
strname = InputBox(Prompt:="You Search String please.", _
         Title:="ENTER SEARCH STRING", Default:="Your Search String here")

Set myFolder = FSO.GetFolder(txt)
For Each subfolder In myFolder.SubFolders
    cnt = 0
    If (InStr(LCase(subfolder.Name), strname)) Then MsgBox ("found string" & subfolder.Name)
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, should be `txt = "//10.4.32.33/"`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But It says folder name not valid. Actually if i enter into a shared folder through getfolder command, it works one more change i need to do in that case is : set myfolder=FSO.getfolder(spath). But same does not work when i goto scroll over list of shared folders in an IP address.

Comment: There is a conceptual problem, you try to `GetFolder("\\10.4.32.33")` but `\\10.4.32.33` is not a drive or a folder.  You cannot do this with the FSO.  In other languages you would use the `NetShareEnum()` API but you cannot call this from VBScript.  Other options are perhaps using WMI to look at the remote machine or to capture and parse the output of `net view \\10.4.32.33`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Shell.Application` ActiveX instead of `FSO`, here is an example:

```
Sub ShowSharedFolders()

    Const SHCONTF_CHECKING_FOR_CHILDREN = &H10
    Const SHCONTF_FOLDERS = &H20
    Const SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS = &H40
    Const SHCONTF_INCLUDEHIDDEN = &H80
    Const SHCONTF_INIT_ON_FIRST_NEXT = &H100
    Const SHCONTF_NETPRINTERSRCH = &H200
    Const SHCONTF_SHAREABLE = &H400
    Const SHCONTF_STORAGE = &H800
    Const SHCONTF_NAVIGATION_ENUM = &H1000
    Const SHCONTF_FASTITEMS = &H2000
    Const SHCONTF_FLATLIST = &H4000
    Const SHCONTF_ENABLE_ASYNC = &H8000
    Const SHCONTF_INCLUDESUPERHIDDEN = &H10000

    strPath = "\\10.4.32.33\"

    Set objShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = objShellApp.Namespace(strPath)
    Set objFolderItems = objFolder.Items()
    objFolderItems.Filter SHCONTF_FOLDERS + SHCONTF_INCLUDEHIDDEN, "*.*"

    For Each objFolderItem In objFolderItems
        Debug.Print objFolderItem.Name & vbTab & objFolderItem.Path
    Next

End Sub
```

For early binding `Set objShellApp = New Shell` you have to add the reference to Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation (Shell32).

Comment: OOH thank u , thank u so much, this is what i wanted.